# how to select group as whole in ng-select angular

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

I am using Angular ng-select component to have searchable , multi-select dropdown with group. I wanted to have functionality where if i select group all  items under that group will get selected.

I am trying to replicate the code which is provided in demos [here](https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select#/grouping)

But, not able to have same functionality.

you can find my code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jdujch?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade your [ng-select](https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select#/grouping) package from `2.1.0` to `2.14.0`

**Changes :**
Change version on package.json from `"@ng-select/ng-select": "2.1.0"` to `"@ng-select/ng-select": "^2.14.0"`